# Expo config plugin for application auto-starting on Android

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

I'm using react native with expo SDK (0.48) and I'm trying to make some modifications to my app to automatically boot it at the startup of the tablet (I'm making a kiosk for Android).

So far I'm looking at https://stackoverflow.com/a/6392009/5320409 and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-launch-an-application-automatically-on-system-boot-up-in-android/

With that in mind, I started creating a custom configuration plugin

```
import {
  AndroidConfig,
  ConfigPlugin,
  withAndroidManifest,
} from "expo/config-plugins";

export const withAutoStart: ConfigPlugin = (config) => {
  return withAndroidManifest(config, async (props) => {
    config = AndroidConfig.Permissions.withPermissions(config, [
      "android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED",
    ]);

    return props;
  });
};
```

But I'm struggling to go further, does anyone has experience with that or has made such plugin? Or just some guidance on what I should look at? I'm not even sure a plugin is enough as it seems I need to make a `.java` file for the BroadcastReceiver... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this solution and it works well. But some of the devices are still not open the app on boot, I have to press the home button then it will open. Here is [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77653621/14724118).

I am open to better solutions.